# Discord.py | outputs only bot in cycle

Tags: python, discord.py

```
...
                        for row in cursor.execute(f"SELECT message, guild_id FROM messages WHERE channel={message.channel.id} and rowid = abs(random()) % (SELECT max(rowid) FROM messages) + 1"):
                            mess=row[0]
                            guildd=int(row[1])
                            server = bot.get_guild(guildd)
                            print(f"server have {server.member_count}")
                            for guild in bot.guilds: #here starts my problem <----------------
                                if guild.id == server.id:
                                    for member in guild.members:
                                        print(f"member {member.name} guild {guild}")
                                        memid=str(member.id)
                                        if memid in soob:
                                            print(f"message contains {memid}")
                                            mess=mess.replace(memid, '0')
                                    break
...
```

outputs is only
(**member [bot name] guild [current guild].**)

No information about other members of guild.

It's like it doesnt see any members in the guild other than himself.

This part of code is responsible to bot cant mention users

Comment: You have to activate the `members` intent to have the complete list of members in a guild. [You can see that here.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.members)

Comment: Thanks for help. I found the solution